# Python delete element from JSON causes unicode errors

Tags: python, json, unicode

I have a list of US counties that I downloaded from Wikipedia using import.io, but it produced several elements for each county that I want out of the document (e.g. the URL's).

I am really confused because I thought JSON docs were in Unicode, although I've seen similar questions/answers on this topic say just pop or delete the element. When I try to pop or delete I get an error saying you can't del unicode and there's no pop in unicode. What am I missing?

Example entry in the JSON Doc

```
`
"data":[{"state/_text":["Alabama"],
"county":["http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autauga_County,_Alabama"],
"state":["http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alabama"],
"state/_source":["/wiki/Alabama"],
"state/_title":["Alabama"],
"county/_title":["Autauga County, Alabama"],
"county/_text":["Autauga County"],
"county/_source":["/wiki/Autauga_County,_Alabama"],`
```

My Code:

```
`import json`

`countiesDoc = json.load(open("US_Counties.json"))
    for element in countiesDoc:
        del element["county"]`

`open("updated_US_Counties.json", "w").write(
    json.dumps(countiesDoc, sort_keys=true, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
)`
```

Traceback:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "edit_us_counties.py", line 10, in <module>
    del element["county"]
TypeError: 'unicode' object does not support item deletion`

`Process finished with exit code 1`
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): the relevant code, the input to that code, and the exception (with traceback) that you get when running it.

Comment: This is not an MCVE. Please read the linked help. Your code should be complete—as in runnable, including any needed input. And post the entire traceback, not just one line from it.

Comment: I'm sorry. I cannot seem to get a good example of the json doc. Import.io freezes constantly and the doc it outputs is just a continuous text file with no formatting.

Answer (score 1):

`countiesDoc` should be a Python `dict` after loading.  Iterating over a `dict` returns the keys, which are strings; therefore, `element` is a string.  Example:

```
import json

jstr = '''\
{
    "element":"value",
    "other":123
}
'''

doc = json.loads(jstr)
print('doc',type(doc))
for e in doc:
    print('e',e,type(e))
```

Output:

```
doc <class 'dict'>
e element <class 'str'>
e other <class 'str'>
```

I don't know the format of your document, but you probably just want the following assuming `county` is a key:

```
del countiesDoc['county']
```

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing a few things.

JSON can encode all kinds of things—numbers, booleans, strings, arrays or dictionaries of any of the above—into a big string.

The server uses JSON to encodes an array or dictionary to a big string, then sends it over the wire to your program. You then need to *decode* it to get back an array or dictionary (in Python terms, a `list` or `dict`). Until you do that, all you have is a string. And you can't `pop` or `delete` from a string.

---

So:

```
import json

j = <however you retrieve the JSON document>
obj = json.loads(j)
del obj['key_i_want_gone']
```

And of course if you want to send the modified dictionary back to the server, or write it to a text file, or whatever, you're probably going to need to re-encode it as JSON first:

```
j = json.dumps(obj)
<however you save or upload or whatever a JSON document>
```

---

The reason you're getting error messages about Unicode is that in Python 2.x, the name of the type that holds Unicode strings is `unicode`. So, when you call `pop` on that string, you're trying to call a method named `unicode.pop`, and there is no such method.

It's basically just a coincidence that the API you're using to fetch the document gives you a Unicode string, and JSON is defined as encoding to Unicode strings, and JSON can take Unicode strings as one of the things it can encode, and so on. (Well, not a coincidence. Most new APIs, document formats, etc. use Unicode because it's the best way to be able to handle most of the characters in most of the languages people care about. But the error has nothing to do with whether or not JSON's strings are Unicode or something different.)

Comment: so why does this return a unicode error?
`countiesDoc = json.load(open("US_Counties.json"))
for element in countiesDoc:
    del element["county"]`

Comment: @AutomaticStatic: I don't know what "this" you're referring to, or what you mean by "return a unicode error". That's why I asked you to post a complete example. You asked why it's "saying there's no pop in unicode", I guessed at what your code and your error probably look like, and explained why that would fail. Have I guessed wrong? Or not explained it well enough?